# How to add entries to an empty dictionary using a formatted key, and update the value using the same key?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to make an appointment calendar application in Python.

I have this empty dictionary called `appointments` and I'm trying to add appointments. It's working but for some reason it's not accumulating the appointments:

```
appointments = {}
while (True):
(... I had a choice variable here that would ask the user to either make an appointment, cancel, or view list of appointments. but for right now, i am only focusing on making appointments.)

    elif choice == 1: #Making an appointment
        apptDate = input('Enter date (mm/dd/yy)\n')
        apptTime = input('Enter time (hh:mm)\n')
        apptDesc = input('Enter a brief description of the appointment\n')

        #Checking to see if key in dictionary
        if apptDate not in appointments:
           newAppt = apptTime + '\t' + apptDesc
           appointments[apptDate] = newAppt
        else:
           appointments[apptDate] = newAppt
```

1. I have to place `apptTime + '\t' + apptDesc` in the `appointments` dictionary using `apptDate` as the key. I thought I was doing this right.
2. Check to see if `apptDate` is already in the `appointments` dictionary because it affects the way that it supposedly adds the new appointment.

Comment: You probably have a bug. When you check `appointments[apptDate]` you are ignoring that one could have appointments at different times the same date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purposes use a [`defaultdict` from `collections` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). This allows you to initialise your dictionary to give a key a certain value if the key is not already in there. In your case you may want to consider each date having a list of appointments, so if there are no appointments, the default dict is initialised with an empty list:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def default():
    return []

appointments = defaultdict(default)
```

Then, whenever you want to add an appointment to a key, you just do

```
appointments['date'].append("Info")
```

This is pretty clean, and avoids the checking statements.

If you insist doing it your way, your last paragraph can be:

```
if apptDate not in appointments:
    newAppt = apptTime + '\t' + apptDesc
    appointments[apptDate] = [newAppt]
else:
    newAppt = apptTime + '\t' + apptDesc
    appointments[apptDate].append(newAppt)
```

Comment: Sure that's a cleaner way but I have not learned this method yet. I believe my instructor wanted me to do the program as such, but i'm just having trouble adding the appointments into the dictionary that consist of the same dates.

Comment: ok, my edit (or something like it) should give you the desired behaviour. I.e now you have a list for each key

Comment: Oh thats what I had before but it wasn't working properly because i did not put [] around newAppt. does having the [] around newAppt affect it? If so, how?

Comment: yep, it makes each dictionary item into a list. Then when you want to add info, you append to the list

Answer (score 0):

```
appointments = []
```

is a list

```
appointments = {}
```

is a dictionary

to check if a key is in a dictionary use

```
if key in dictionary:
```

(where key would be apptDate)

Comment: Oh yes, sorry that was a typo.

Comment: Would this be okay?

if apptDate in appointments:
            newAppt = apptTime + '\t' + apptDesc
            appointments[apptDate] += newAppt
        else:
            print('Date not in dictionary.')

Comment: that is where i am having issues when it comes to adding appointments in the dictionary

Comment: use a default dict instead of doing the above, its way easier